# Is there a way to get the offending duplicate row on constraint violation exception?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an insert from select statement in oracle:

```
insert into T1(c1,c2,c3) 
values (v1,v2,v3)
(select v1,v2,v3) from ...)
```

and I get an  ORA-00001 - UK constaint violated.

Is there a way to get what row is throwing this exception?

Comment: I assume you mean other than doing a preemptive check for existing values?

Comment: No, I mean getting the offending row along with the exception message

Comment: That was somewhat rhetorical - there may be some system-level logging or something you can dig into but typically  the easiest way is to proactively check before inserting.  There's not a "standard" sql way that I'm aware of.

Comment: I know that, but I'm afraid I can't: as you can see from my code values are taken from a select...